# Firebase AppCheck iOS gives an error when generating appcheck token error code 0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-app-check

When I run my app from xcode on my iPhone 12 Device, I get an error when trying to generate the Firebase AppCheck Token from below method. The error code is 0 and there is no description in the error object.

```
AppCheck.appCheck().token(forcingRefresh: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just found out this might be cause by one of two issues below

1. Enable AppAttest in Capabilities
2. Set AppAttest environment to production even in testing since The App Check beta currently doesn't accept tokens generated in the App Attest sandbox environment.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider#install-sdk